# How to Change Android Theme using Custom Theme Style

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have declared my own custom theme xml and named it style

`<style name="LightTheme.PSIProjectAPP" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar.Bridge">`

Then i tried to change the manifes theme, `setTheme()` and filled the paramater with `android.R.style`, but can't find my custom style.

How do i do it? or there is a way to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you want, you can apply the defined style to the activity or view that you want stylized like this:

in the manifest file:

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.MyGreenTheme"/>
```

Comment: how to do it programmatically? I forgot to mention that I want to make switch theme dynamically